# *ngIf Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I need to move a project out of angular, and thus need to change many of the directives i've been using. I was wondering if anyone knew what I could change the *ngIf directive to in plain javascript?

example:

```
<li *ngIf="currentLanguage !== 'en'"><a onClick="changeLanguage('en') "hreflang="en"><img class="flag" src="assets/languages/en.png" alt="">{{'NAVIGATION_EN'|translate}}</a></li>
```

Comment: Are you abandoning frameworks altogether? HTML simply does not support anything like this.

Comment: you cant do it with plain javascript inside HTML document, please, specify which JS framework you will be moving to?

Comment: sorry, just regular javascript

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe target elements with `*ngIf` attribute :

```
let conditionals = document.querySelectorAll('[*ngIf]');
```

And then loop on each, getting the condition, and display the element or not ?

```
for (conditional in conditionals) {
  condition = conditional.attr('*ngIf');
  if (!condition) {
    conditional.className += ' hidden';
  }
}
```

I didn't test this code, but it looks like an good way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround can be:

```
<li id="myId" class="hide"><a onClick="changeLanguage('en') "hreflang="en"><img class="flag" src="assets/languages/en.png" alt="">{{'NAVIGATION_EN'|translate}}</a></li>
```

on css:

```
.hide{
  display: none; 
}
```

on JS:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('myId');
if(currentLanguage !== 'en'){
  ele.style.display = "block";
}
```